# calling setBackgroundColor on UILabel causes crash

Tags: ios, objective-c, exc-bad-access

Okay so I have been pulling my hair out, TRYING to find the cause of this problem in my code, and I've narrowed it down to a single line. The problem is, it doesn't make any sense. I create a UIViewController and put this code in the init method

```
- (id)init
{
    [super init];

    [self.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor groupTableViewBackgroundColor]];

    iCodeAppDelegate*appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    UIWindow*window = appDelegate.window;

    int headerY = appDelegate.rootNavigator.navigationBar.bounds.size.height;// + [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarFrame.size.height;

    //project options table
    int tableOffsetY = 250;
    UITableView* projectOptions = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, headerY+tableOffsetY, window.bounds.size.width, window.bounds.size.height-(headerY+tableOffsetY)) style:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
    projectOptions.delegate = self;
    projectOptions.dataSource = self;
    projectOptions.scrollEnabled = NO;

    [self.view addSubview:projectOptions];
    [projectOptions release];

    //xcode logo image
    int centerX = window.bounds.size.width/2;
    int logoOffsetY = 8;
    int logoScale = 200;
    UIImage* xcodeLogo = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Images/xcode_logo.png"];

    UIImageView* xcodeLogoView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(centerX-(logoScale/2), headerY+logoOffsetY, logoScale, logoScale)];
    [xcodeLogoView setImage:xcodeLogo];
    //[xcodeLogoView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor groupTableViewBackgroundColor]];

    [self.view addSubview:xcodeLogoView];
    [xcodeLogo release];
    [xcodeLogoView release];

    //"Welcome to Minicode" text
    int welcomeLabelHeight = 50;
    UILabel*welcomeLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, headerY+logoScale+8, window.bounds.size.width, welcomeLabelHeight)];
    [welcomeLabel setText:@"Welcome to miniCode"];
    [welcomeLabel setTextColor:[UIColor darkGrayColor]];
    [welcomeLabel setTextAlignment:UITextAlignmentCenter];
    [welcomeLabel setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [welcomeLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName: @"Trebuchet MS" size: 24.0f]];
    [self.view addSubview:welcomeLabel];
    [welcomeLabel release];

    return self;
}
```

The problem lies in this specific line:

```
[welcomeLabel setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
```

if I comment it out, the code works fine, except that the label has a big white box behind it. I've scoured the internet, and it appears only one person has had a similar problem. [The solution doesn't seem to have any sort of application to my code, however.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6625822/setting-uilabel-background-color-causes-app-to-crash)

Comment: You should show us the property declaration of welcomeLabel.

Comment: it was declared inside init. that was my bad. I was testing it before as a property inside the view controller to see if that would work, and I forgot to fix it before I posted the code. I just changed it back

Comment: can you post the crash?

Comment: Program received signal:  “EXC_BAD_ACCESS”.

Comment: Have you tried welcomeLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor] ?

Comment: yeah it just causes the same error

Comment: The 'init' method should assign the result of '[super init]' to 'self';

Comment: as in, self = [super init]?

Comment: have you tried Zombies instrument to see what is being accessed to cause the exception?

Comment: I will try that out, but I was really hoping someone would have had this error before, because I didn't even add anything that complicated to the program

Comment: so I added another view into the application, and now the setBackgroundColor isn't the line that's causing the problem. It's setting the UIImage to the UIView. Also, all of these crashes only occur after I minimize the app, open it back up again, and go back to the main viewController

Comment: So I followed [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3780708/my-iphone-app-crashes-after-returning-from-background-cause-uiimage-problem) and now it works. Can someone tell me why exactly the UIImageView didn't retain my image?